# What is proper way to redirect to page after successful login with Auth0?

Tags: angular, auth0

After logging in to my app with Auth0, I am trying to subscribe to the successful completion of the login, then redirect to the page requested, but the line highlighted never gets called.  Very new to Angular2 and Observables and need to know if there is a better way or what i'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: After some playing, the .subscribe() is running before the Auth0 Lock component renders.  Then login with creds, and .subscribe() doesn't run again, so no redirect.

[image]

Comment: If the highlighted part doesn't get called I don't think you receive the response from the back-end. Do you see the response in the network tab?

Comment: @echonax Updated the post...   subscribe does run, just runs before user logs in.  after successful login, no additional events are fired.  Perhaps I'm just not using the Auth0 Lock component correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed the official Auth0 docs and put the redirect right after the users profile is set. Here is the code from the official doc...

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

        this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error, profile) => {
            if (error) {
                alert(error);
                return;
            }

            profile.user_metadata = profile.user_metadata || {};
            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
            this.userProfile = profile;
        });
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    });
}
```

Specifically they use the `this.router.navigate(['/Whatever'])`

Hope this helps. here is the official doc https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/04-user-profile

Wherever you choose to put the actual routing is up to you, just make sure you pass in the router.

**EDIT**

this is the Url I ment to post for the Auth0 doc https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/02-custom-login Notice how they handle the redirect in the constructor rather than the login function.

Comment: i'm implemented and it seems to be working because the url address in browser changes to /home, but in Edge/Chrome/IE it doesn't render /home, still shows login button.  works in Firefox.... very strange